# Enable seamless mode for kalilinux

Tags: virtualbox, desktop-environments

I'am in ubuntu 14.04 ,  Windows 2012 work fine with seamless mode in virtualbox but Kalilinux the seamless mode is disable. i had install Guest Additions and enable 3d and 2d acceleration.